# Entity framework Find result vs LINQ result

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am a new .NET developer. I have 2 entity classes like this

```
public class Student
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Course course { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int courseId { get; set; }
    public String courseName { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the DB Context Object like this

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
```

When I access the Student object using

```
Student stdent = db.students.Find(1);
```

the member variables of native type(int,string) in the student object contains values but course variable of type(Course) is returned null.

Whereas, when I use

```
var result = from student in db.students where student.userId == 1 select student;
```

the result contains values for all member variables(entire course object is present here)

**Is this the expected behavior or am I missing or overlooking something?**

I even added this constructor in my DB Context to disable Lazy Loading but didn't help

```
    public MyDbContext() : base()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that in the first case (Find) you fetch an object from the database. `Course` is not lazy loading, so the `Course` reference is `null`.

In the second case you're only defining a query but not executing it. I assume that you loop through the results afterwards and a the same time check whether `Course` is present. That causes `Course` to get loaded because you access the `Course` navigation property at execution time, it has become part of the query.

If you do

```
var s = (from student in db.students where student.userId == 1 select student)
        .Single();
```

you will notice that `Course` is empty, because the student is fetched without a reference to `Course` at the moment the query is ececuted (the `Single` statement).

Comment: In the first case, Even if I set lazy loading to false(as I have said in the question) and try to access course, it still gives me null. Any idea why is that.

Comment: Yes, it will never lazy load, because the property is not virtual. Irrespective of lazy loading settings of the context. It's only loaded by _eager loading_. Which is, either through `Include` or by addressing it in a linq query like `Students.Select(s => s.Course)`, or by the `Load` method.

Comment: I think part of your confusion is that the opposite of "lazy = false" (at the context level) does not mean "eager = true". With "lazy=true" lazy loading occurs if possible (i.e. with `virtual` properties). With "lazy=false" _no_ loading will occur unless explicitly demanded by the three options I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies things a lot

Answer (score 0):

With lazy load only the initial object is loaded. In order to get the second option to retrieve the Course information you will need to specify in load options.

```
DataLoadOptions dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Course);
db.LoadOptions = dataLoadOptions;

Student stdent = db.students.Find( c=>c.userid == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```